# apt-get error on openhabian when calling '/usr/lib/apt/methods/http'

Tags: apt

I hope I'm right here, some days ago apt-get broke on my Raspberry Pi Model B rev. 2 (running Openhabian). I'm not sure why yet and wasn't able to fix it myself.

When I try to `apt-get update` as root I get the following output:

```
[15:58:05] root@openHABianPi:/home/openhabian# apt-get update
Reading package lists... Done
E: Method http has died unexpectedly!
E: Sub-process http received signal 4.
E: Method /usr/lib/apt/methods/http did not start correctly
E: Method https has died unexpectedly!
E: Sub-process https received signal 4.
E: Method /usr/lib/apt/methods/https did not start correctly
E: Method https has died unexpectedly!
E: Sub-process https received signal 4.
E: Method /usr/lib/apt/methods/https did not start correctly
E: Method https has died unexpectedly!
E: Sub-process https received signal 4.
E: Method /usr/lib/apt/methods/https did not start correctly
E: Method https has died unexpectedly!
E: Sub-process https received signal 4.
E: Method /usr/lib/apt/methods/https did not start correctly
E: Method http has died unexpectedly!
E: Sub-process http received signal 4.
E: Method /usr/lib/apt/methods/http did not start correctly
E: Method http has died unexpectedly!
E: Sub-process http received signal 4.
E: Method /usr/lib/apt/methods/http did not start correctly
E: Failed to fetch http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/dists/stretch/InRelease
E: Failed to fetch https://apt.homegear.eu/Raspbian/stretch/InRelease
E: Failed to fetch https://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/stretch-backports/InRelease
E: Failed to fetch https://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/dists/testing/InRelease
E: Failed to fetch https://dl.bintray.com/openhab/apt-repo2/dists/stable/InRelease
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/dists/stretch/InRelease
E: Failed to fetch http://repos.azulsystems.com/debian/dists/stable/InRelease
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

When I try to check the version of `/usr/lib/apt/methods/http` (https is a link to that) I get the following output:

```
[15:59:05] root@openHABianPi:/home/openhabian# /usr/lib/apt/methods/http
Illegal instruction
```

I have `apt-transport-https` installed. I also did `apt-get autoremove` and there may be some dependences missing from whatever package `/usr/lib/apt/methods/http` is part of, even tough as far as I know that shouldn't happen.

Thank you for your help!

Edit 1:

```
[23:11:36] root@openHABianPi:/home/openhabian# dpkg -i apt_1.4.9_armhf.deb
dpkg: warning: downgrading apt from 1.8.0 to 1.4.9
(Reading database ... 47399 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack apt_1.4.9_armhf.deb ...
Unpacking apt (1.4.9) over (1.8.0) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of apt:
 libapt-pkg5.0:armhf (1.8.0) breaks apt (<< 1.6~) and is installed.
  Version of apt to be configured is 1.4.9.

dpkg: error processing package apt (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.28-8) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.6.1-2) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 apt
```

I installed [libapt-pkg5.0_1.4.9_armhf.deb](http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/pool/main/a/apt/libapt-pkg5.0_1.4.9_armhf.deb) and then was able to install [apt_1.4.9_armhf.deb](http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/pool/main/a/apt/apt_1.4.9_armhf.deb)

I still have the problem that apt-get update freezes with `0% [Working]` at one source, this may still be caused by incompatible sources.

Edit 2:
The problems were caused by a wrong source originating from a letsencrypt/certbot-setup, I got rid of all remaining problems by removing the source, pinning my packages to stable (was using "now" for a lot of packages) and basically doing a very careful `apt-get dist-upgrade` with a lot of manual checking. You may have to exclude https sources temporarily even with apt-transport-https installed as it didn't work for me too (failed with "Illegal instruction" on call of `/usr/lib/apt/methods/https` because of dependencies).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm hoping your `dpkg` still works ok... On my Debian/MX system (also based on Debian stretch), the `/usr/lib/apt/methods/http` file is part of the `apt` package, checked with `dpkg -S /usr/lib/apt/methods/http`.

Browsing through what might be your main repository http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/dists/stretch/InRelease and specifically looking in http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/dists/stretch/main/binary-armhf/Packages (it's 59M) I see it's got

```
Package: apt
Version: 1.4.9
```

Which is the same version number as mine too. So I'm guessing your `apt` package was messed up somehow, perhaps an incompatible version from another source "upgraded" it? You can check your apt's version with one of:

- `apt-cache showpkg apt`
- `apt-cache show apt` if apt-cache still works, or
- `dpkg -s apt`
- `dpkg-query --show apt`

Hopefully it's not 1.4.9, so you can try installing this version. Browsing more through the repository, 
http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/pool/main/a/apt/ has the [apt_1.4.9_armhf.deb](http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/pool/main/a/apt/apt_1.4.9_armhf.deb) file.

[It's [mirror list is here](http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/pool/main/a/apt/apt_1.4.9_armhf.deb.mirrorlist), with other download links.]

If you download the .deb. file, and install it with

```
dpkg -i apt_1.4.9_armhf.deb
```

that should install a hopefully good version of apt.

Be careful not to "upgrade" apt again to a possibly broken version, I'd check the source of any candidates with `apt-cache policy apt` and maybe remove "bad" sources, or consider pinning `apt` to a good source only (see `man apt_preferences`) or locking it's version.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, you were spot on, dpkg works, apt isn't version 1.4.9 and I also tried to install that exact version before posting here because I thought it was already installed, but it turns out that I actually have 1.8.0 installed and changing to 1.4.9 throws errors (I added the output to the original post)

Comment: So downgrading libapt-pkg5.0 fixed things? That's good, at least this problem got solved, if my answer was helpful please do select it as correct (click the check-mark next to it) & even upvote if you're able. I'm not sure about the one source not downloading, maybe it's just down for now?

Comment: Yes, I'll try the solutions from [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/498462/apt-get-stuck-at-0-working) now, hopefully they'll completely solve it since I don't use small lists that are likely to go offline.

I marked and upvoted your answer, though the upvote won't show for now since my account is new. Thank you again!

Comment: I'd still guess it's a not fully compatible source, but I don't know enough about raspberries & openhabian to guess which. I had similar problems using www.deb-multimedia.org with my MX/Debian, that source was a little different & has some weird version numbers (like 2:1.4.5 that get installed instead of a newer 1.6), I kept it for a small handfull of codecs but pinned it's priority to never auto-install (I think 50), but removing it & manually installing a couple packages should've worked too. Welcome & thanks for the check, I think you still need a couple more rep points to upvote, ah well.